# Java equivalent of C# Delegates (queues methods of various classes to be executed)

Tags: java, c#, delegates

TLDR:

Is there a Java equivalent of C#'s [delegates](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-delegates) that will allow me to queue up methods of various classes and add them to the queue dynamically? Language constructs instead of the code for it.

Context:

I have used Unity 3D before and I love things like the `Update` method of scripts. Just declaring the method adds it to the list of methods executed each frame. I want to create something like that in my LWJGL game. For this, I would want to use delegates (or something equivalent to it). Is there any Java language construct that would allow me to do this? I would prefer answers that include two or more (so that I can pick and choose which will be the most optimal for my code) constructs and a way of using them. I don't want the code, I just want to know where to start. The most fun part of programming is working the problem out and I don't want to be deprived of that. Also, I don't want to be told EXACTLY how to do it. I want to be guided in the right direction instead of being thrown in that direction onto that destination. How would I learn? :-)

Comment: The library safety-mirror adds delegates and events to Java. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63777276/6095334, or better, the project's README: https://github.com/Hervian/safety-mirror.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extracted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx :

> A delegate in C# is similar to a function pointer in C or C++. Using a
>   delegate allows the programmer to encapsulate a reference to a method
>   inside a delegate object. The delegate object can then be passed to
>   code which can call the referenced method, without having to know at
>   compile time which method will be invoked. Unlike function pointers in
>   C or C++, delegates are object-oriented, type-safe, and secure.

That said, Java does not have delegates like C#. **However**, since Java 8, we do have some sort of function pointers by using [method references and functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

As you politely requested, I am not going to tell you exactly how to implement this code, but you should be able to come up with a solution with this information.

Comment: This answer takes my request to the extreme but it doesn't give me the code I need... which is nice. However, an improvement for future questions like this is to not assume that I know about things like Interfaces and other intermediate (and beyond) skills as I now have to research about Interfaces etc. Just a suggestion for your future answers. Thank you btw

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I will take it into account next time.

Answer (score 29):

Actually there is no exact counterpart for delegates in Java. But there are constructs that mimic their behavior.

## Java 8

### Functional interfaces

The concept that comes closes to delegates in Java 8 is that of *functional interfaces*.

For example, if you have a C# delegate:

```
delegate void Runnable();
```

in Java, you would create a functional interface like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Runnable {
    void run();
}
```

The nice thing about functional interfaces is they can be used easily in [lambda expressions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lambda_expression).

### Example

So, let's suppose you have the following class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void someStaticMethod() {
    }

    public void someMethod() {
    }
}
```

### Lambda expressions and method references

With Java 8, you get lambda expressions.

```
List<Runnable> queue = new ArrayList<>();
queue.add(() -> someMethod());
queue.add(() -> someStaticMethod());
```

There is a short-hand named *method reference* for this, if you actually simply call a method:

```
List<Runnable> queue = new ArrayList<>();
queue.add(this::someMethod);
queue.add(SomeClass::someStaticMethod);
```

## Java 7

With Java 7, the only thing you can use is [anonymous classes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anonymous_class):

```
List<Runnable> queue = new ArrayList<>();
queue.add(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        someMethod();
    }
});
queue.add(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        someStaticMethod();
    }
});
```

I hope this was not too much information, so you can still learn. ;-)
However, I like my answer to be useful also for other people looking up this question.

Comment: Looking back on this a year and a bit later, I am still learning things from this answer due to actually understanding more of it and am questioning why I asked the question in the way I did (wanting to reinvent the wheel by requesting for little information). In particular, the method reference part is an interesting feature because it reminds me of c(++) namespace member access. You get a long overdue upvote :)

Comment: @JamesYeoMan: Thanks for that :-)

Yeah, actually StackOverflow is the place for providing good and quality answers and not for giving "hints" ;-)

The C++ thingy is probably just a coincidence... They just needed a syntax in Java for _method_ _references_ and went for that.

Answer (score 2):

java function interface != c# delegate. From the consumers' side, you won't be able to get any detailed information other than a pure c-style function-pointer. You cannot tell whether a java function interface is binding some objects as a lambda expression or a member function, or just a static method with zero dependencies. I'd say c# delegate provides some very interesting features, may be not that important, to help diagnostic potential program defects like thread-safety of a delegate.