# Can Java receive and invoke a delegate of static method received from another language?

Tags: java, c#, objective-c, unity-game-engine, delegates

For example, in C# I have

```
[MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(PointDelegate))]
public static void Callback(int x, int y)
{ .... }
```

This method is stored in a delegate of signature return void (int, int).

```
public delegate void PointDelegate(int x, int y);
```

I sent this delegate variable to Objective-C and over there I was able to call it directly to invoke `Callback()`. It just works. (I have declared the equivalent `typedef` at Objective-C side to match)

C#

```
objC(Callback);
```

Objective-C

```
typedef void (*PointDelegate)(int x, int y);
void objC(PointDelegate delegateFromCSharp)
{
   delegateFromCSharp(1,2);
}
```

What is the equivalent in Java? Assuming I can call a method in Java already and the delegate is being passed as the only parameter, what would be the signature of that Java method? And how to invoke the received delegate?

Comment: Its called native. Look at implementation of Thread for example http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java

Comment: Java has no concept of delegates, you can use functional interfaces & method references (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346343/java-equivalent-of-c-sharp-delegates-queues-methods-of-various-classes-to-be-ex).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working. This solution uses Unity's ["AndroidJavaProxy"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaProxy.html) class so I am not sure what it will be using pure JNI. But I am glad it works for my case.

This is C# :

```
public class IntInterface : AndroidJavaProxy
{
    public IntInterface() : base("com.YourCompany.YourApp.YourClass$IntInterface") { }
    void Call(int i)
    {
        Debug.Log("Java says : " + i);
    }
}
```

Then I call static method on Java with `new IntInterface()` as a parameter.

At Java side I have a matching interface waiting. It can accept `IntInterface` from C# side without throwing `JNI : unknown signature for type` anymore. The `Call` is also being matched with C# ones.

```
    public static void StaticMethod(IntInterface intInterface) {
        intInterface.Call(555);
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface IntInterface{
        void Call(int i);
    }
```

The result is `"Java says : 555"` I just invoked C# method `Call(int i)` with parameter from Java.